# gdaldem slope attribute passing

Tags: latitude-longitude, slope, gdaldem

## How to pass slope attribute to the command

```
   "gdaldem slope manj.tif outpiu.tif -p use percent 45 -s 111120/370400"
```

> It's giving error like FAILURE: Too many command options.
>
> > give any working example for my understanding perpose.

Comment: Swith -p is on/off and -s takes a plain number thus this syntax should work
`gdaldem slope manj.tif outpiu.tif -p -s 10` Try with -s 111120 if dem is in EPSG:4326 and uses degrees as vertical units.